# Updating Feature Service that ArcGIS Online Feature Layer points at

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, feature-layer, feature-service

I have a Feature Service hosted on my ArcGIS Server and exposed to the internet (something like this Layer: Rainfall(NOAA) (ID: 0)). I added this Feature Service to my AGOL org by going to Content >  Create > Feature Layer > From URL and entering the REST URL of my Feature Service (I ended up with something like this: https://geodecisions.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=caa1b120e1ac4fa497866e0ba4cdcd9e). Now I would like to change the Feature Service to a different service on my ArcGIS Server while keeping the same Feature Layer item id. Thie would allow me not to have to update the Feature Layer URL in a few applications that I have that use this Feature Layer.

Is this possible?

I have looked around in the Feature Layer settings and tried the ArcGIS Online Assistant but haven't found anything that works.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible (I would also like to know if it is).  In the past, when I've wanted to do this, I overwrite the feature service on the ArcGIS Server instead.  Of course, this can have other problems.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the optimal way, but When using Arcgis Pro, you can right click any local layer > sharing > overwrite web layer. So export the desired layer to local FGDB, then do the steps above.